# How to print return type with boolean method in output?

Tags: java

I created method that called bubble sorted method, but I want to that this method can return with output boolean type, if the array of elements sorted this method can return in output true, if the array of elements is not sorted, than in output print false.

```
public static boolean sorted(int[] arr) 
{ 
    int temp = arr[0]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length-1; j++) 
        { 
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) 
            { 
               temp = arr[j];  //2 
               arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; 
               arr[j + 1] = temp; 
           } 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method to check if the array is sorted:

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] arr){ 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) 
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) 
               return false;
   return true
}
```

and used it as you want.